# If item not in the store, dispatch an action to fetch it

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to fetch an item if it's not in the store.

For instance, let say that I have a list of users and I want to fetch a specific user. If that user isn't in the store I want to fetch him from the DB.

Is this code below considered best practice or is there a better way doing so?

```
const searchedUserId = 'abcdefg'; 
this.selecedUser$ = this.store.select(state => {
   const selectedUserIndex = state.userList.findIndex(searchedUserId)
   if (selectedUserIndex === -1) {
     this.store.dispatch(new UsersActions.FetchUsers(searchedUserId));  
   } else {
     return state.userList[selectedUserIndex]
   }
})
```

Comment: Stores should be the only source of data in your application. So if the user is not in the store, you should dispatch an action to fetch data and update the Store, and then you should retrieve the data from the store.

Comment: But in order to fetch the user, I need to listen to the store.
And only inside the selector i can do that check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a guard.

1. Define a route for your user details component (which contains id)
2. Define a guard for that route and put it in CanActivate
3. In guard, dispatch the LoadUserDetailsAction(userId)
4. When that action resolves (guard listens for store when details are loaded) return true so that your component can be shown
5. Its now safe to do store.select(userdetails) in yoir component

Comment: A guard is even worse practice then what I asked above. A guard should prevent you from accessing a page, not for loading more data. If I wanted that approach I could just use the resolve method.

Comment: Noone said guard is loading any data except you :). Guard does precisely what its intended for: makes sure you don't activate component thats not ready for it. Not loading a single piece of data. Your idea of using resolve method together with state is pretty strange since that way you're doing exactly the opposite of what state management is intended for: single source of truth for your app. But if you consider that as good practice, who am i to stop you ;)

Comment: First of all I appreciate your help. But on this issue I still think that gaurs is not the right solution. I'm positive that on this approach, resolve will be the better way. But anyway it's not cover what i need

Answer (score 1):

```
const searchedUserId = 'abcdefg';
this.selecedUser$ = this.store.select('userList').pipe(
  map(userList=>{const result = userList.findIndex(item=>item.id===searchedUserId);
  return result === -1 ? {} : result;
  }),
  tap(userList=>{
    if( !userList.hasOwnProperty('id') ) this.store.dispatch(new UsersActions.FetchUsers(searchedUserId));
  })
);
```

tap will not change the observable and when the dispatched action will change the state, the observable will be updated.

Use an selector instead of the select statement and be aware about the situation the action will not found the key.

Answer (score 0):

if it's not in the store nor fetched then your application doesn't need this piece of information. usually this kind of logic will go into `guards`, `initializers`, `resolvers` or any other logical method to fetch this kind of data.

If i'll look at the flow you described then in order to reach the user page you are talking about I'll have to click on something to navigate to that page or even just collapse a card or something similar.

At this point after the event happened then your application have several different ways to do that, either send a request/dispatch action which fetch the data, either with a `guard`/`resolver`.

Subscribing inside the store itself to the store data and fetching more data based on the store state is bad practice and will lead to infinite loops, issues with debugging and figuring out who fires what.

Comment: This is completely untrue... if I have a dashboard that is the default page and I want each widget to be in the store then I need to fetch it.

Comment: The solution is to use a guard

Comment: you comments make no sense at all since I mentioned guards as one of the solutions, and incase you are loading the default page which requires certain data then you can utilize all of the above methods I've mentioned to fetch the data previous to showing it.

Comment: It’s unrelated to a click. This can also be true after a page refresh

Comment: it's event based, like most of the things that happen on the browser... 'click', 'pageloaded', navigator.onLine, etc... for a case you mentioned you can use the ngOnInit lifecycle.
my point is that letting your state management decide when to fetch what is bad practice. he should receive actions based on actions/events that happened by a user interaction (99% of the time).

Comment: This is the way we went https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/preloading-ngrx-store-route-guards though we are removing the attire completely now as it really unneeded practice in Angular

Answer (score 0):

I came to this as I had a similar situation where I don't want to make the http request if the data is already present in the store.

As far as I see it the following would be acceptable and still keep the separation of concerns with regards to selectors / effects / store etc.

1. Create selector to return user from store.
2. Dispatch your fetch action in the component's init.
3. Inside the effect use the selector to query the store. If the selector returns null then request the data from the back-end.
4. Return the user in a fetchSucceeded action
5. Update store in reducer on fetchSucceeded

[How to Use State Inside of an Effect Component With ngrx](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-state-into-effect-using-ngrx)

Answer (score -1):

Create a `selector` to fetch the data from the store.

[Creating a selector](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md)

In your component, you need to `subscribe` to the state.

```
store.select(selectFeatureState).subscribe(state => {
    //Search for the user in the state.
    // If user is not there then dispatch the action
    store.dispatch(ACTION);
});
```

Then, create `Effects` using @ngrx/effects

[create effects](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/README.md)

Effects listen for the actions, and then calls the service, retrieve the data and update the store.

As the store is already subscribing to the store, it will update the component.

Comment: I understand how the store/effects works. I asked if the code I wrote (which you actually wrote as well) considered to be best practice